# Bitmasking and bit manipulations with C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit, bitmask

I've been trying to understand how bit operations work with C and pointers but no luck. Here is my problem. I have 8 bytes in memory and need to extract the first 61 bits and print. For example:  0000 0000..... 0010 0111 , I need to extract the value 32 (ignoring the last 3 bits from 64 bits.) How does this work in C? All i have is a pointer to the start of the 8bytes.

```
uint_64_t* myPointer;  // already pointing to start of 8bytes

typedef struct Solve{
    uint64_t myBytes: 64; // set a field thats equal to 64 bits
}

struct Solve s1;

s1.myBytes = *myPointer>>3; //failed attempt

printf("Bytes are %" PRIu64 "\n", s1.myBytes); // just prints out 0 when should be 32
```

Comment: You have not shown how you set the value at `*myPointer`, and `uint64_t myBytes: 64;` is a syntax error. You are also mixing signed and unsigned types. Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.

Comment: Where is `0000 0000..... 0010 0111` or its equivalent coded?

Comment: If you expect 32 from the binary you posted you need to mask off the low 3 bits. `val &= ~(1<<3-1);`

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to print a 64 bit value with the 3 low order bits cleared, take the value and perform a logical AND with a bitmask that has all but the lowest 3 bits set:

```
uint64_t myvalue = 0x0123456789abcdefULL;
uint64_t masked_value = myvalue & 0xfffffffffffffff8ULL;

printf("Bytes are %" PRIx64 "\n", masked_value );
```

Output:

```
Bytes are 123456789abcde8
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear lower order 3 bits in your 64 bit variable. Since you were interested in the manipulation of the structure field value, I have included such example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#define B(x) S_to_binary_(#x)

typedef struct solve{
    u_int64_t myBytes: 64; //  field that has 64 bits
}Solve;

static inline unsigned long long S_to_binary_(const char *s)
{
    unsigned long long i = 0;
    while (*s) {
        i <<= 1;
        i += *s++ - '0';
    }
    return i;
}

int main(void)
{
    u_int64_t mask = ~0; // This will give you 1111...1111
    mask = mask<<3;      // This will become   1111...1000

    Solve * myPointer;       

    Solve s1;                  // declare the structure s1
    s1.myBytes = B(100111);    // init the myBytes to 38 (decimal)

    printf("Initial value of s1.myBytes is: %lld\n", s1.myBytes);      

    myPointer = & s1;          //  cannot take address of bit-field 'myBytes' directly
    myPointer->myBytes = (myPointer->myBytes & mask);   // change the value of myBytes 

    printf("Now     value of s1.myBytes is: %lld\n\n", s1.myBytes);    // print new value

    // more testing 
    uint64_t myvalue1 =  0x0123456789abcdefULL;
    uint64_t myvalue  =  B(100111);  

    uint64_t masked_value1 = myvalue1 & mask; // This will clear low 3 bits
    uint64_t masked_value =  myvalue & mask;  // This will clear low 3 bits

    printf("Bytes are: %" PRIx64 "\n", masked_value1 );

    printf("Value is: %lld\n", masked_value );

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Initial value of s1.myBytes is: 39
Now     value of s1.myBytes is: 32

Bytes are: 123456789abcde8
Value is: 32
```

Let me know if these examples solve your problem.

Comment: I think you misunderstood I'm just asking how I would return the Most significant 61 bits. So for example, if the 64 bits were 0000.....0010 0111 in memory, how can i print out the value 32 and ignore the LeastSignificant 3 bits

Comment: @tylerC You might also want to concern yourself with the Endian of the machine; byte order.